# add row number to the last column using awk or bash

Tags: bash, awk

Input file format:

```
name id department
xyz  20  cic
abc  25  cis
```

Output should look like:

```
name id department
xyz  20  cic        1
abc  25  cis        2
```

Note: all the fields are tab separated.

Appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'NR>1{$0=$0"\t"NR-1} 1' file
name    id      department
xyz     20      cic     1
abc     25      cis     2
```

Comment: Thank You all for the prompt response!! can this be achieved with awk/bash.. input file 
tbname id  department
xyz   20   cic
xyz   21   csp
xyz   22   cpz
abc   25   cis
abc   26   cta
abc   27   tec


outout file
tbname id  department
xyz   20   cic          1
xyz   21   csp          2  
xyz   22   cpz          3  
abc   25   cis          1 
abc   26   cta          2
abc   27   tec          3

reset column number based on tbname and all fields are separated by tab

Thanks much!!!

Comment: The posted solution IS awk. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
awk '{printf "%s\t%s\n",$0,NR}' File_name
```

Explanation:

$0 = print all the lines

NR = Adds number at each line

%s = for printing a literal character

\t = hozintal tab

\n = new line

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

A variation on Ed Morton's answer:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NR>1 { $(NF+1)=NR-1} 1' file
```

This sets the output field separator using the `-v` option, then simply adds a new field to the current record by setting `$(NR+1)`.